# Change of Variables Integration

Tags: integration

Find the volume enclosed by the cone $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and the plane $2z — y — 2 = 0$.

What I have so far is converting the triple integral into polar coordinates

The bounds for the integral are
$$\frac{y+1}{2}<z<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$0<r<\frac{2}{2-\sin(\theta)}$$
$$0<\theta<2\pi $$
I end up with a function that doesn't seem integratable but all the problems in this set are supposed to be doable without using programs. Any help is appreciated in where I went wrong

Comment: Take a look at the edits I made to your posts. It is worth learning some LaTeX if you will be using this website.

Comment: Is the resulting integral $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2 - \sin(\theta)} \, d \theta?$$ Mathematica says the answer is $\displaystyle \frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}$ and I think it used complex analysis.

Comment: What function did you end up with?